# How can I set an initial value for the textfield?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have these textfields to update an item. How can I set an initial value for the productName and productPrice?

I already have these productName and productPrice data which was taken from a row in the previous page and was stored in this edit form in a `location.state`.

I already have these data stored in the `location.state`:

1. productName - Item1
2. productPrice - 2.00

Currently, if I am going to update the data and will only enter a value in the product price field, the product name field would be saved as an empty string in the firestore. I wanted to set an initial value for each of the textfield with their corresponding data so that even if the user will only update the product price field, the productName will be saved as it is "Item1" and won't be save as an empty string. I tried having a defaultValue and it does not work.

```
const edit = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const data = location.state;
  const [Product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState("");
  const [productPrice, setProductPrice] = useState("");


  useEffect(() => {
    firestore
      .collection("products")
      .doc(data)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const arr = [];
        arr.push({
          ...snapshot.data(),
        });
        setProduct(arr);
      });

  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const Ref = firestore.collection("products").doc(data);
      const res = Ref.set(
        {
          productName,
          productPrice,
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
      alert("Successfully updated");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
        {products.map((prod, index) => (
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <FormControl>
                <TextField
                  id="input"
                  type=”text”
                  label="Product Name"
                  value={productName}
                 defaultValue={prod.productName)
                  onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)}
                />

                <TextField
                  id="input"
                  margin="dense"
                  type="text"
                  label="Product Price"
                  value={productPrice}
                  defaultValue={prod.productPrice)
                  onChange={(e) => setProductPrice(e.target.value)}
                />



                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  
                >
                  Update
                </Button>
              </FormControl>
            </form>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default edit;
```

Comment: try to set the state after getting the response

Answer (score 1):

> I already have these data stored in the location.state:
>
> - productName - Item1
> - Blockquote

productPrice - 2.00

What about this?

```
const location = useLocation();
const [productName, setProductName] = useState(location.state.productName);
const [productPrice, setProductPrice] = useState(location.state.productPrice);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is provided that the variable named data has the default product details

The state could be initialized in this way

```
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState(data.productName);
  const [productPrice, setProductPrice] = useState(data.productPrice);
```

So these default values will be picked up by the text fields

Answer (score 0):

In the onChange prop, try to check if e.target.value is not empty, else assign the old or the default product name.

```
onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value ? e.target.value : prod.productName)}
```